# Retrieve values according to foreign keys in asp.net core mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have to 2 tables (employeeinfo, employeehiringdetail). I have saved employeeinfo and then want to save employeehiringdetail, from employeehiringdetail controller i used redirectoaction to employeeprofile view where i just passed employeehiringdetail model, and then i want to show employee name but emplyee name is empty.
Models:
employeeinfo { empid,empname,status)
emphiringdetail(id, empid,hiringdetails).

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't provide enough information in your question, My thoughts may be a little different from yours.

In my opinion, You create `employeehiringdetail` in `EmployeehiringdetailController`, Then you want to redirect to another view to show the information about `employeehiringdetail` you just created and it's corresponding `emplyee`, you can refer to this demo:

```
public class EmployeehiringdetailController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;
        public EmployeehiringdetailController(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(employeehiringdetail model)
        {

           
            //...........

            //save the employeehiringdetail  you just created into database and pass fk as parameter


            return RedirectToAction("actionName","ControllerName", new {param = model.empid});
        }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public employeehiringdetail modelA { get; set; }
        public employeeinfo modelB { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in another View:

```
public IActionResult employeeprofile(int param)
        {
            ViewModel model = new ViewModel();

            model.modelB = _context.employeeinfos.Where(x => x.empid == param).FirstOrDefault();

            model.modelA = _context.employeehiringdetails.Where(x => x.empid == param).FirstOrDefault();


            return View(model);
        }

==========================================

@model ViewModel

<h1>@Model.modelB.empname</h1>
<h2>@Model.modelA.hiringdetails</h2>
```

Comment: thanks shen for the reply, specifically in my case i have only on controller for all like home, so when i pass id (fk) as parameter along with controller and action name it passes null. I m using .net 5, but when i pass only action name and id then its ok. Any ways problem solved thanks for your support